# Using python's subprocess.call or os.system inside a chroot jail

Tags: python, linux, chroot

Ok, the situation is a bit hard to explain.
I have a user in an SSH chroot jail.
I copied some binaries and all the necessary libraries, and it works.
However, when I try to use os.system or subprocess.call inside python (or system in C for that matter) It refuses to work. (both in absolute and relative path).

For example:

> >> import os
>
> >> os.system('/usr/bin/ls')
>
> 32515 # Means that it can't find the file
>
> >> os.listdir() # To make sure i'm in the jail
>
> ['etc', 'usr', 'lib64', 'home', 'dev', 'lib', 'bin'] # The expected output of the jail's root directory
>
> >> os.listdir('/usr/bin')
>
> ['id', 'cat', 'scp', 'less', 'ls', 'whoami', 'vim', 'nohup', 'python', 'bash'] # Clearly ls is here

outside of python (and inside the jail) the ls command works just great.

If anyone has any insight to what's going on I would be grateful.

Edit:

The nice people in the comments noted that using subprocess without shell=True works. I would like an explanation of why that works, and maybe an alternative for c/c++. Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried `os.system('ls')` ? isn't there a protection against running external processes?

Comment: Same results. os.system great outside of the jail, and the ls command works great inside the jail.

Comment: have you tried to open the file for reading? `open('/usr/bin/ls')`

Comment: Tried it now and it works. Finds the correct file and reads the correct content... I guess it something to do specifically with execution.

Comment: maybe an issue with user group.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What about use groups can cause such an error?

Comment: Just a very, very wild guess, a problem from yesteryear. What if Python tries to execute commands with /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash or directly loading them in with C:s execv()?    What if you tried in your bin directory ln bash sh to ensure /bin/sh is also available?

Comment: yeah: using `subprocess` with `shell=True` could lead to the same problem. Can you switch back to `subprocess.call` _without_ `shell=True` ?

Comment: Wow that works. I think I must have shell=True because I want to send a shell prompt over a socket in Python. But it's definitely a step in the right direction